# Buffering a Float32Array to a client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, stream

This should be obvious, but for some reason I am not getting any result. I have already spent way too much time just trying different ways to get this working without results.

**TLDR**: A shorter way to explain this question could be: I know how to stream a sound from a file. How to stream a buffer containing sound that was synthesized on the server instead?

**This works:**

- client:

  ```
  var stream = ss.createStream();
  ss(socket).emit('get-file', stream, data.bufferSource);
  var parts = [];
  stream.on('data', function(chunk){
        parts.push(chunk);
   });
   stream.on('end', function () {
        var blob=new Blob(parts,{type:"audio"});
        if(cb){
           cb(blob);
        }
   });
  ```
- server (in the 'socket-connected' callback of socket.io)

  ```
  var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
  // ....
  ss(socket).on('get-file', (stream:any, filename:any)=>{
    console.log("get-file",filename);
    fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
  });
  ```

**Now, the problem:**

I want to alter this audio buffer and send the modified audio instead of just the file. I converted the ReadStream into an Float32Array, and did some processes sample by sample. Now I want to send that modified Float32Array to the client.

In my view, I just need to replaces the `fs.createReadStream(filename)` with`(new Readable()).push(modifiedSoundBuffer)`. However, I get a `TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk`. Interestingly, if I convert this `modifiedSodunBuffer` into a Uint8Array, it doesn't yell at me, and the client gets a large array, which looks good; only that all the array values are 0. I guess that it's flooring all the values?

```
  ss(socket).on('get-buffer', (stream:any, filename:any)=>{
    let readable=(new Readable()).push(modifiedFloat32Array);
    readable.pipe(stream);
  });
```

I am trying to use streams for two reasons: sound buffers are large, and to allow concurrent processing in the future

Comment: HI @Joaquin, did you manage to modify audio on the server and send it back to client in real time?

Comment: hi! Sorry I did not come back with the results later, which generally I think people should do. This was long ago. I think I did not manage to solve the problem and had to work around. I am sure there is a solution, though. If it's worth spending the time is another question.

Answer (score 0):

if you will convert object Float32Array to buffer before sending like this Readable()).push(Buffer.from(modifiedSoundBuffer)) ?

Comment: now it doesn't show errors, but it's not recognized as audio on the client any more. I will keep finding out why another day. There might be too many variables at play

Comment: In any case stream is working with string or buffer. For sending object you need switch to "object mode". just read about it in man.